# Android: How to prevent the MenuItems in navigation drawer from invalidating?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, menu-items

I'm developing an android app, it uses a navigation drawer, it has only one `Activity` : the MainActivity, and the rest are all `fragments`.

Now the `action bar` has 3 `Menu Items`, one of them is a play button for a live radio stream and its drawable is a `play` image, when i press the button i have implemented a code in the MainActivity `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`to change the button's drawable to a `stop` image.

Now when i navigate to another fragment using the `Fragment Transaction`; the live stream item returns to its initial state which is a `play` drawable. I think the Menu is recreating itself (i don't know).

How can i preserve the Menu Items state all the time ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding onPrepareOptionsMenu might work. You could maintain a Boolean variable and check its state in onPrepareOptionsMenu to decide what should be the drawable for your menu item.